# Why do we have to name the collection at the end of a mongoose model

Tags: node.js, model, mongoose, schema

I cannot understand why I can access to my model using this :

```
module.exports = function(mongoose) {
    var collection = 'news';

    var NewsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        type: String,
        content: String,
        img: String,
        date: {type: Date, default: Date.now }
    });

    return mongoose.model(collection, NewsSchema);
}
```

But I have to specify the name collection to access to this model:

```
module.exports = function(mongoose) {
    var collection = 'console';

    var ConsoleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        value: String,
        label: String
    }, { collection: collection });

    return mongoose.model(collection, ConsoleSchema);
}
```

I access to my data using

```
models.news.find({});
models.collection.find({});
```

I don't understand the tricks...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Mongoose uses the lower-cased, pluralized version of the model name for the default name of the underlying collection.

So `'news'` maps to `'news'` (because it's already plural), but `'console'` maps to `'consoles'`, so you need to explicitly set the collection name using the `collection` option on the schema.

You can also set the collection name using the third parameter to [`mongoose.model`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model):

```
return mongoose.model(collection, ConsoleSchema, collection);
```